# Updating a Set from a Map argument in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, treeset

I have this school question:

The method should returns no value but should take as its argument a map whose keys are strings and whose values are integers. The strings represent person numbers and the integers the respective sales figures. The map entries do not need to be in any particular order.

For each Person in personSet your method should check whether its personNumber is one of the keys in the map. If so, the sales for that Person should be increased by the map value corresponding to that key.

This is the code i got, obviously it's incorrect, any pointers?

```
public void updatePersons (Map<String, Integer> pers)
   {
     for (Persons all : personSet)
     {
        if (all.getPersonNumber().equals(pers.keySet()))
        {
          personSet.add(pers);
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: `personSet` contains `Persons` objects. How do you intend to update that set with an `Integer` value obtained from the Map?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. I think your data-model might be flawed.. Try raising the level of abstraction in your question a bit and perhaps provide more context..

Comment: Please provide the code of the `Persons` class.

Comment: where does the `i` come from? And I don't see where you use the `all` variable.

Comment: You can't iterate over a set using foreach and manipulate the set in the loop body - you'll get an exception. Besides that your code doesn't make much sense as has already been stated. You probably want to query the map using `get(...)` and update the person object whose number you used for the lookup.

Comment: So the String holds the personNumber and the integer value should assign a reference number to that personNumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a lot of code is missing I'm working on some assumptions:

If you want to update the reference number of the persons in the set based on the map you can do it like this:

```
for (Persons person: personSet) {
  Integer reference = pers.get( person.getPersonNumber() );
  if( reference != null ) {
    person.setReference( reference );
  }
}
```

You iterate over all persons and query the map for the value associated with the person number. If such a value exists you update the person and go on with the next person.

Note that if the reference number is used to sort the set you'd have to remove and reinsert the person to preserve order.

Comment: I have updated the question, would the reply still stand? Thank you!

Comment: @seawork yes the reply still stands just with the difference of "the sales for that Person should be increased by the map value corresponding to that key" - i.e. you need to add the value instead of just setting it. Besides that please tell us the question/task right from the start before trying to mask it in contradictory statements/code.

Comment: I wasn't trying to mask anything pal, I was trying to keep the question simple. Thanks

Comment: @seawork well, in that case it was too simple and the edit didn't add that much more text but a lot more information :)